# Mudar cor do link da navbar de acordo com a posição da página

Tags: javascript, html, css

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para mudar a cor de cada link da minha navbar, de acordo com a sessão que estou na página, se alguém poder me falar o nome dessa técnica agradeceria também.

Ex:

estou na página home, então a borda fica preta, ai eu desço e vou pra página de serviços, então o link de serviços na minha navbar quem fica preto. Grato desde já.

Comment: acho que não tem um nome para essa tecnica, basta usar o evento `onmouseover` para saber se está sobre algum elemente e por teu script para mudar a cor nesse evento

Comment: O que vc está querendo fazer se chama Scroll Spy, e para isso vc precisa detectar que a próxima sessão entrou na tela e colocar colocar uma classe Ativo por exemplo no  link do menu que corresponde a sessão que entrou na tela.